# Almost complex structure on $\mathbb CP^2 \mathbin\# \mathbb CP^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Why doesn't $\mathbb CP^2 \mathbin\# \mathbb CP^2$ admit an almost complex structure?

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are compact four-manifolds which admit almost complex structures, then $X\# Y$ does not. Even more generally, if two of $X, Y, X\# Y$ admit almost complex structures, the third does not. Both of these facts follow from the necessary condition stated in Jason DeVito's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59820/a-question-on-classification-of-almost-complex-structures-on-4-manifolds), a necessary condition for a $4$-manifold to admit an almost complex structure is that $e+\tau = 0 \pmod 4$, where $e$ is the Euler characteristic and $\tau$ is the signature.  (I don't know of a reference for that fact).

But $\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp \mathbb{C}P^2$ has euler Characteristic $4$ (its homology groups are that of $S^2\times S^2$) and its signature $\tau$ is $2$ (since the identity represents the bilinear form in the "usual" basis of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp\mathbb{C}P^2)$.)

Then $e+\tau = 6 \cong 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: If anyone happens to know of a reference for the fact that $e  +\tau = 0 \pmod{4}$ for a $4$-manifold admitting an almost complex structure, I'd love to know one.

Comment: You can deduce this from knowing that $c_1^2$ is equivalent to $\tau$ mod 2 (and using the formula from Wu involving $c_1^2$ and $p_1$), which is ultimately a result of $c_1$ being a characteristic element of the cup-product pairing on $H^2$. I would imagine that stuff like this is found in Milnor's book on quadratic forms, or Scorpan's "Wild World" book.